# Reassigning string literals

Tags: c, string, pointers

This is a really basic question but I did not find a clear answer. I try to understand how string literals in `C` work.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
        char *str = "Hello World!";
        str = "Reassign str.";

        char *str2 = "Something.";

        str = strdup(str2);

        free(str);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I do `str = "Reassign str."` or `str = strdup(str2)` to a string literal what happens to the `Hello World` string? Is it part of the executable, does it go out of scope, is it's memory freed after I reassign `str`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals have static storage duration. They are not destroyed and have the same addresses during the program execution.

In these statements

```
    str = "Reassign str.";
    //...
    str = strdup(str2);
```

pointer `str` is just reassigned by some other addresses. In the first statement it gets the address of the first character of string literal  "Reassign str." and in the second statement it gets the address of the dynamically allocated  memory for the character array that contains a copy of the string literal pointed to by str2.

According to the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 6 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to
>   each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal
>   or literals.78) The multibyte character sequence is then used to
>   initialize **an array of static storage duration** and length just
>   sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the
>   array elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual
>   bytes of the multibyte character sequence.

And (6.2.4 Storage durations of objects)

> 3 An object ...has static storage duration. **Its lifetime is the
>   entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized
>   only once, prior to program startup**

As for the string literals themselves then you may not change them. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behaviour of the program.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

For example you may not write

```
    char *str = "Hello World!";
    *str = 'h';
```

Comment: Is it ok to reassign string literals the way I did?

Comment: @brauner You are not reassigning string literals. You are reassigning pointers that previously pointed to first characters of the string literals.

Comment: You didn't reassign a string literal. The literal is the bit inside the `""` marks. You reassigned `str` which is a pointer. It originally pointed _at_ the literal, and then you pointed it at some dynamically allocated memory instead.

Comment: @brauner String literals have the same storage duration during the program execution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Imprecision on my part!

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
char *str = "Hello World!";
```

compiler sets aside memory of bytes `strlen(str) + 1` for that string literal.  When the pointer `str` being reassigned, the memory allocated for string literal `"Hello World!"` is not destroyed/freed, rather it persist in its scope.

Answer (score 2):

All is Ok in your code.

```
    char *str = "Hello World!";
```

Ok you declare a `char *` pointing to a string litteral. To be correct, you should have written `const char *str =` because a string litteral is an unmodifiable string (`str[4] = 'u';` would be incorrect)

```
    str = "Reassign str.";
```

Ok the pointer str now point to another string litteral. Same remark as above, it should still be const.

```
    char *str2 = "Something.";
```

Still same story

```
    str = strdup(str2);
```

Now str points to  a malloc'ed string. For the first time it is correct for str not to be const. `str[0] = 's';` would be correct here.

```
    free(str);
```

Fine, you free the string allocated by `strdup`.

```
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

You nicely return a defined value (0) to the environment.

Comment: Technically, a string literal does not have `const` type. You shouldn't write to it though.

Answer (score 2):

As if there weren't enough answers already, but I think one aspect is still worth mentioning:

Yes, it's correct that a string literal in your code has static storage, so it will be *alive* during the whole program execution. In that terms, nothing can ever *happen* to it (you can't even change it). Technically, that means normally that the string is *part* of your program and put in a *data* segment that is read only.

But, in your case, an optimizing compiler will detect that `"Hello World!"` is never actually used, so it will disappear from your compiled program. That's a legal thing for an optimizer to do, because it doesn't change the *observable behavior* of your program.

```
> gcc -ostrlit strlit.c
> strings strlit | grep Hello
Hello World!
> gcc -O3 -ostrlit strlit.c
> strings strlit | grep Hello
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally static strings are in a static data section.  In this case, because you program does not do anything, I'm not so sure; all your static strings may be optimised away.

In a real program, where you'd actually use these static strings, they would have a fixed address.

By no means does the `str = strdup(str2);` free any memory.  In C memory is never freed by itself.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I mangled the `strdup()` in there without a `free()`.

Comment: The `free()` you added now simply deallocates the memory allocated by `strdup()`; nothing happens with the previous assigned static string.

Comment: Yeah, I know I just considered it bad form to not have a `free()` in there.

Comment: Ah I see.  No worries.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down:

```
char *str = "Hello World!";
```

declares a *pointer to char* called `str`

```
char *str
```

and *also* declares a string literal

```
            "Hello World!";
```

and *also* sets `str` to point at the first character of the literal.

The literal has static storage duration - it is compiled into your executable, is always there, and can't be moved or altered.

The pointer is just a pointer, and you can point it at other things whenever you like.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a string literal such as this:

```
char *str = "Hello World!";
```

The `"Hello World!"` string is stored in a read-only section of memory.  So if you one of these:

```
str[1] = 'i';
strcpy(str, "Goodbye!");
```

You'll most likely core dump.  If on the other hand you do this:

```
str = malloc(10);
strcpy(str, "Goodbye!");
```

You'll be fine, although you'll loose the pointer you had to the original string.